# Destructor runs with every method call of a class

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code. Every time a method like `wypisz()` is called, a destructor also runs every time and prints "us" on the screen. I want it only to be called when the program will end. I'm new to C++ and I don't know what I have done wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

class Matrix
{
    private:
        size_t dim;

    public:
        std::vector<std::vector<double> > matrix;

        Matrix(size_t dim_) : dim(dim_), matrix()
        {
            matrix.resize(dim); // zmiana wymiarów macierzy
            for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
                matrix[i].resize(dim);
            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
                }
            }
        }

        void wypisz(Matrix m)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    std::cout << m.matrix[i][j] << " ";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }

        void add(Matrix m, Matrix n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    std::cout << m.matrix[i][j] + n.matrix[i][j] << " ";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
            }
        }

        ~Matrix()
        {
            std::cout << "us \n";
        }

};


int main()
{
    Matrix Mac(3);
    Matrix Mac2(3);
    Mac.wypisz(Mac);
    Mac2.wypisz(Mac2);
    Mac.add(Mac, Mac2);
}
```

Comment: Because `wypisz` accepts argument by value. Use reference. `void wypisz(Matrix& m)`

Comment: Why accepting argument by value cause the problem ?

Comment: Passing by value means the function gets its own copy of the argument, which needs to be constructed on entry and destroyed upon return from that function. As an aside, your instances of `3` in both `wypisz` and `add` look like they should probably be `dim` instead?

Comment: @PiotrNowakowski Because passing by-value means a copy is made. At the end of the function, the argument's copy is destroyed.

Comment: Side-note: You made instance methods that don't use the instance they're called on (`this`), so they pointlessly have to pass the instance manually every time. Using `this` for `wypisz` would remove the need for an explicit argument at all, allowing you to call it with the simpler `Mac.wypisz();`, saving pointless repetition. Similarly, `add` should probably only take one argument (the other `Matrix` to operate on), and it should be by `const` reference (since you don't change it). And both methods should be declared `const` themselves (`this` is never mutated).

Comment: @EOF Thank You for help and clarification now it works

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes yes thanks

Comment: This also applies to the `add` function. Only it does not change the arguments, so it makes sense to declare the parameters as `void add(const Matrix& m, const Matrix& n)`.

Comment: @PiotrNowakowski Consider `void foo(int i) { i = 8; }`. Do you think the caller of that function has access to that 8 somehow? If so, where? Consider `foo(5);`. Where does the 8 go? You have that same problem with all your `Matrix` functions. They modify a parameter passed by value and give their callers no way to access the modified values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why accepting argument by value cause the problem ?

All objects with automatic storage are destroyed automatically. When you call a function with object parameters<sup>1</sup>, those objects are created at the beginning of the function call and destroyed when the function returns. When object is destroyed, the destructor is run.

If destructor being run is your problem, then creating of the objects is the cause of your problem. Don't accept object parameters if you don't want those parameters to be objects. If you want a parameter to not be a newly created object, but instead to indirectly *refer* to some other object passed as an argument, then use a reference parameter.

---

<sup>1</sup> By "object parameter" I mean a parameter that has an object type as opposed to a parameter that has a reference type - which is commonly known as a reference parameter. The evaluation strategy that is used when passing argument to such object parameter is commonly called "call by value" or "pass by value".

Comment: I think term "object argument" is confusing, common one IMHO is to pass by value.

Comment: @Slava I think value is confusing. References are values too.

Comment: Maybe, but object argument is even more confusing.

Comment: @Slava Then we disagree.

Comment: Pass by value vs pass by reference is a common term and used widely. Where this "object argument" term comes from?

Comment: @Slava I actually meant that to be object parameter. It comes from the parameter being an object as opposed to a reference. I prefer to use less ambiguous terms even if they aren't yet in common use.

Comment: If the term is not in common use, then I suggest explaining what it means, or linking to a source that uses it. I know what you mean in the answer, but the terminology is confusing (mostly because it's not commonly used).